# How to create a Asmx Client for Wcf Service

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, asmx

I have some clients calling my asmx service and I figure out to change my asmx to a Wcf service.
How can my asmx clients call to my Wcf service without modify the client application?

Maybe just a few changes in the config file...

I can't expect than they compile their applications.

Comment: Answered on StackOverflow Link: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502298/how-much-effort-is-required-to-convert-an-asmx-to-wcf-web-service)

Comment: Please see the reply at the following link.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/30482561/4944540

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [following article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312490/Migrating-ASMX-Services-To-WCF-services) illustrates a detailed guide on how you could achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to support [basicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) in your WCF server and provide new URL to your `basicHttpBinding` endpoint to callers.

Callers only need to change URL they use.

Everything should happen behind the scene for them.